# Mysql compare max in without sub query's

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to compare a column with i'ts max, is it possible with a single query?

I want something like that:

```
where data = max(data)
```

i could achive the desired result with something like that:

```
where data = (select max(data) from data_table)
```

but i don't want to implement a subquery to do that, is there any way to do it without the subquery?

**Obs:** There is no problem with subquery's, that all about query performance, the date column is indexed and still causes performance issues when i apply subquery on the where clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ...and anyway, what's wrong with subqueries?

Comment: It's more about not having to use join's in a subquery, so it wont slow my querys (even more).

Comment: In that case, the premise of the question is flawed. 'Joins in subqueries' are not necessarily a key factor in query performance. Your attention would be better directed towards an appropriate use of indexes, but until you provide a proper question, we can't really help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery, something like this:

```
select *
from tableA tab1
where tab1.data = (select max(tab2.data)
                   from tableA tab2)
```

Comment: That's my fault, i edited the title when i've saw that i wasn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to be much clearer, because if it is not exactly clear what you want, and why (why wouldn't you want a subquery?!?), you will get multiple answers, not all of which work. Just for the heck of it, let me give you one:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The subquery's works nicely when you don't have to join them, like if there is a complex query and i want to create a subquery with it, it causes the query to get slowers and the code to get more complicated.

Comment: Are you deliberately providing an example of an answer which won't work?

Comment: @Strawberry Hehe of cours not ;), but I should have said: "that might not give the result you desire, since the result you desire is not well defined". Of course the example provides  a perfect answer to the question -- if "data" is unique. Since the circumstances are not given, people will either ignore the question or make them up foir themselves. The last thing is what I did.

Comment: @Wel You will have to provide the queries in question because every situation is unique. Sometimes subqueries are WAY more efficient, sometimes not. We can only guess now, like I did. I also can guess that you should have a look at HAVING instead of WHERE, which is generally slower but can make queries a lot simpler/shorter. It all depends on the specific situation.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is the perfect answer to any question, but I suppose an sqlfiddle would put the matter beyond contention

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the SORT BY. I changed it. I just keep on doing that wrong, even thought  I started with SQL in '87. Bit corny not to just point it out, isn't it.